# should weights be scaled too?

Tags: classification, svm, multidimensional-scaling, supervised-learning, optimal-scaling

I am using supervised learning algorithms (specificly SVM) on my data.
I know that scaling was needed for my input data. however as I am also adding weights (using pairwise comparison), I am not sure if my weights need to be scaled as well.

I don't mean normalizing the weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about data weights, I dont know. In fact I am not sure that any of the standard SVM implementations have data weights (each data point has a weight). If you are talking about CLASS weight, at least in the libSVM implementation, they are multiplicative terms

-wi weight: set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)

(from the libSVM page http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ )

so there is no gain in scaling them.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, yes scaling would  not have worked with the regular matlab svm, it works better with libsvm.  SVM normalizes everything.